# Play Framework 2.1.0 - NoClassDefFoundError when registering JDBC driver using Class.forName

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, olap4j

I am trying to use olap4j with Play 2.1.0 but am having great difficulty in getting some olap4j code to work in a Play controller, this same code works just fine in a separate Eclipse Java project, hence I have ruled out any issues with olap4j or my XMLA server it connects to.  I have added the olap4j JAR files as unmanaged dependencies by placing the JAR files in \lib folder.  I am running in Play DEV mode.

The following code returns the exception below:

**Java Code:**

```
Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
```

**Error:**

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/emory/mathcs/backport/java/util/concurrent/Callable]
```

After some further digging around I found that Play uses it's own Classloader, so I tried the following:

**Java Code:**

```
Play.application().classloader().loadClass("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
```

This seems to eliminate the NoClassDefFoundError error, however the following exception is raised:

**Error:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll
```

Perhaps I need to add the JDBC class registration in a Global class?  Any help would be much appreciated.  The JavaDocs for org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver says the following, which is exactly what I am following:

*Since olap4j is a superset of JDBC, you register this driver as you would any JDBC driver:
    Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver"); 
Then create a connection using a URL with the prefix "jdbc:xmla:".*

**Full Code:**

```
package controllers;

import play.Play;
import play.mvc.*;
import org.olap4j.*;
import org.olap4j.metadata.Member;
import java.sql.*;

public class Test extends Controller {

public static Result index() {

    String server = "http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String result = "0";

    try {
        //Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
        Play.application().classloader().loadClass("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:xmla:Server="+server, user, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }

    return ok(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763413/jdbc-connection-from-play-app?rq=1), your first approach should work just fine, e.g. this:

```
Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
```

The error you're getting,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/emory/mathcs/backport/java/util/concurrent/Callable
```

implies that you need to add `backport-util-concurrent.jar` also to your class path (like mentioned in [this thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2281&t=236325)). I guess it should work after that. That jar is Backport Concurrent Util jar, available [on its site](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/). Place that also into your lib folder.

Comment: God bless you!  It's working now, I also needed Retroweaver (http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/net.sourceforge.retroweaver/retroweaver-rt/1.2.4).  It seems like some problem with Eclipse & Play integration as a non-web Java project works without the additional dependencies in Eclipse. Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: np :) it's a bit peculiar that such libraries are needed - as if you were running in some legacy (<1.5) java environment. But great that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using both olap4j and olap4j-jdk14. You only need one of the two.